# JavaScript scripts stop working when page changes the language

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have a WordPress website with Elementor and a language translator installed. A script for getting the price of Ethereum (every second) is located in the block with the HTML code of this element. There are two languages that set on the website - English, and Israel. The point is when I change the language to Israel the page mirrors horizontally. After that, all the scripts on the page stop working.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, there are. It says that variables that I have defined in the code are undefined. It doesn't matter if I rename them, they are still undefined.

Comment: The interpreter probably isn't wrong. Make sure the variables are in scope when you are using them.